# Sound doesn't work after hibernate.

Tags: audio, sound-card

The last few times that I woke my PC out of hibernate, the sound wasn't working. I re-enabled the sound card and reinstalled the driver. It still isn't working. When this happens, Flash will crash when I use it. iTunes doesn't work, just as some other programs.

```
Specs:
Gigabyte GA-MA790x-UD4P and it's on-board sound card
AMD Phenom II x4 955
ATI HD4890
2x2GB G.Skill Ripjaws
Western Digital HDD (not sure which one)
Windows 7
```

There seem to be a lot of errors coming from `ShellHWDetection, MMCSS and AeLookupService`, in my log.

Sample of a `ShellHWDetection` error:

```
System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Service Control Manager 
   [ Guid]  {555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4} 
   [ EventSourceName]  Service Control Manager 

  - EventID 7011 

   [ Qualifiers]  49152 

   Version 0 

   Level 2 

   Task 0 

   Opcode 0 

   Keywords 0x8080000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2011-11-26T11:39:30.513091900Z 

   EventRecordID 545363 

   Correlation 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  624 
   [ ThreadID]  5176 

   Channel System 

   Computer Simon-PC 

   Security 


- EventData 

  param1 30000 
  param2 Schedule
```

Sample of a `MMCSS` error:

```
    System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Service Control Manager 
   [ Guid]  {555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4} 
   [ EventSourceName]  Service Control Manager 

  - EventID 7011 

   [ Qualifiers]  49152 

   Version 0 

   Level 2 

   Task 0 

   Opcode 0 

   Keywords 0x8080000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2011-11-26T11:39:30.513091900Z 

   EventRecordID 545363 

   Correlation 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  624 
   [ ThreadID]  5176 

   Channel System 

   Computer Simon-PC 

   Security 


- EventData 

  param1 30000 
  param2 Schedule
```

And a sample of an `AeLookupService` error:

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Service Control Manager 
   [ Guid]  {555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4} 
   [ EventSourceName]  Service Control Manager 

  - EventID 7011 

   [ Qualifiers]  49152 

   Version 0 

   Level 2 

   Task 0 

   Opcode 0 

   Keywords 0x8080000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2011-11-26T12:12:00.755639300Z 

   EventRecordID 545446 

   Correlation 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  624 
   [ ThreadID]  5908 

   Channel System 

   Computer Simon-PC 

   Security 


- EventData 

  param1 30000 
  param2 AeLookupSvc
```

Comment: Does it work if you shut down and restart? 
When was the last Windows Update?

Comment: Then it does work. I'm not sure, can I check it somewhere?

Comment: Control Panel/System and Security/Windows Update. You may also want to check the computer manufacturer's web site for updates for BIOS and sound. Let us know what you find.

Comment: The last time was yesterday (25/11). Could the BIOS be the problem? It hasn't been updated (that I know of ) since I own the PC.

Comment: You can try updating the BIOS. Make sure you are using the manufacture re's drivers and not the generic ones Windows sometimes assigns.

Comment: Hmm.. Downloaded the update, can't execute it, because it isn't compatible with my 64bit system. No 64bit version available on the website.