# No sound after putting the laptop to sleep or hibernate

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, sound-card

I have a Lenovo running Win7-x64 (SP1), and after I put my laptop to sleep or hibernate, the computer won't play any sound after I wake it. The really strange part is that if I put the computer back to sleep/hibernate, it will play the sound when I wake it. (And it stops playing sound when I put the computer back to sleep/hibernate again). Rebooting the computer will also fix the problem. I have the latest windows updates and drivers.

There is a similar problem posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/361644/sound-doesnt-work-after-hibernate), but there are no answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make sure you've got the latest drivers for your sound card and system board as well as the latest Windows patches.

Power states and drivers enjoy a tenuous relationship at best, and the first step of troubleshooting any issues that appear related to changing power states should always involve making sure the drivers of any and all affected systems are up to date.

Next, check to see if the Windows Audio service is running after after a power state cycle. Start -> Run -> "services.msc" Enter. Check that Windows Audio service status is "Started".

Also, when you're playing audio and there's no audio output, double-click on the volume control in your taskbar and see if the audio level indicator is moving indicating the system "sees" audio passing through the volume control.

Comment: The "Windows Audio" and "Windows Audio Endpoint Builder" are started. And the audio level indicator is moving, but there's no sound.

Comment: Are the drivers updated yet?

Comment: I thought I had thet latest drivers, but apparently not. I updated the audio drivers and the problem resolved itself.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Restarting Windows Audio Endpoint Builder and then enabling the speaker (it had got disabled) on restart, worked for me

Comment: Services.msc (as above) > Windows Audio > "Restart" works for me. (But this isn't an ideal solution as it must be done each time the bug arises, which for me is every time after the PC wakes from sleep.)

Answer (score -1):

Another reason might be, that you put your laptop to hibernate when your earphones connected, but awake it after you unplugged your earphones. Laptop thinks it is still connected to earphones, but the fact is there is no connected earphone.

This is my case, for asus x550j laptop. I didn't find the solution yet. Restarting solves it, I'll look for new solution later.

Comment: I feel this should have been a comment, it doesn't really answer the question. The OP said in the accepted answer that a driver update solved his problem.